# Reference a field within AmpScript in an email

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Within an email, how can I reference a field within Ampscript? For example:

```
%%[ 
var @myname 
set @myname = '%%firstname%%'
]%% 
My Name: %%=v(@myname)=%%
```

Where First Name is a field name in the associated DE. I know I can just use %%firstname%% to get the same result, but wondering if something similar is doable within ampscript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how you use within AMPscript:

```
%%[ var @myname 
set @myname = AttributeValue('FirstNameColumnName')
]%%
```

My Name: %%=v(@myname)=%%

Check out for more info :
https://ampscript.guide/attributevalue/